# How i can make some variables in a url and a text $u1.txt

Tags: php, sql, url

I have a url that already has some variables:

```
api/search.php?name=Carl&name2=Carlos
```

but I copy that to explode the data in arrays to save it in a txt file like

I try

```
$var_c = implode ('', file ('https://awebsite/api/search.php?name=$Variable1&name2=$variable2"'));
```

but i have not the variables in the url the request is 0

then the txt file must save a file from a other Variable

```
$dateiA = "test.txt";
```

I try

```
$dateiA = "$test.txt";
```

the variables not working at all

Does anyone have an idea? thx a lot.

Comment: What is the expected output ? And what do you mean by **the variables not working at all**

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question completly but I think what you need is this:

You can access the URL-parameters like this:
`$urlParameters = $_GET;`

You get an array that looks like this:

```
array(
  'name' => 'Carl',
  'name2' => 'Carlos',
)
```